# Django save-Making Two Orders on single click

Tags: django, django-models

i have created my ecommerce platform. Whenever I click the order-now-buttons, it makes two orders in my backend, I don't see where the error comes from. But it outputs a complete and incomplete, order.Here is my view.py makeorder function

```
def processOrder(request):
    transaction_id = datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    print(data)
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(
            customer=customer, complete=False)
        total = order.get_cart_totals
        order.transaction_id = transaction_id

        if total == order.get_cart_totals:
            order.complete = True
            print("Total equals")
        order.save()
        if order.shipping == True:
            print("Wrong")
            ShippingAddress.objects.create(
                customer=customer,
                order=order,
                firstname=data['shipping']['firstname'],
                lastname=data['shipping']['lastname'],
                address=data['shipping']['address'],
                city=data['shipping']['city'],
                zipcode=data['shipping']['zipcode']
            )
    else:
        print("User doesn't exist")
    print('Data:', request.body)
    return JsonResponse('Payment Submitted', safe=False)
```

I know the error is inside my function, but i cant figure it out
Thanks for your help in advance

Here goes my model.py for order

```
class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

    @property
    def shipping(self):
        shipping = False
        orderItems = self.orderitem_set.all()
        for i in orderItems:
            if i.product.digital == False:
                shipping = True
        return shipping
```

Comment: Do you by any chance make use of signals for one of the models in that view?

Comment: no i dint use signals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to debug your function would be to:

1. Add a conditional to check if created is true or false after the line
   `order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)`
2. You can also add the following print statement `print(Order.objects.all().count())` after the line `order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)` ​and the `order.save()` line,
   and check if the numbers differ, according to the functions logic there should be only one.
3. Make sure that your function is only being called once per button press. I tend to manually test this sometimes with a print statement at the beginning of the function, e.g:

```
def processOrder(request):
   ​print("Executing processOrder")
   ​...
```

On a different note, I would like to suggest a simplification for the `shipping` property that uses the Django ORM more and does not waste time fetching all items from the database to iterate over them in the memory:

```
@property
   ​def shipping(self):
       ​if(self.orderitem_set.filter(product__digital=False).count()):
           ​return True
       ​return False
```